# Make col center Bootstraps

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I create a "col-lg-6 text-center" inside a row but it centered only within the column itself. So I have to add 2 more columns "col-lg-3" to make the col-6 lie at center of the page.

```
 <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-3">

             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                  <p>Some text</p>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3">

             </div>
</div>
```

You guys have any way to make the col-lg-6 centered at the page without 2 col-lg-3? I'm very appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use col-lg-offset-3 to add offset of 3 columns at left

Plunker solution :

https://plnkr.co/edit/B5Ka3V7BHio0v8ZcMcXr

```
<div class="row"> 
         <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 text-center">
              <p>Some text</p>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not yet, I maximized the windows to full screen but it's not in the middle of the page

Comment: it should work fine for large screens , but it will be left align for size md and below. If you want it to be center aligned for all screen sizes user  col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6